# Inner join usage with array

Tags: mysql, set

I try to make a filter for my project. And I want to learn how can I use array values in inner join. For example I have a query like this.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID;
```

But I have multiple `EmployeeID`s in array and I try to make my query like this.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.1,2,3;
```

this is the wrong way I know but I really don't know the right way to make this query.

Comment: Join all the employees then limit them in the `where` clause. `ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID where Orders.EmployeeID in(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about that if there are any number of rows of employee id mapped with the orders it will return that many rows if exist, rather just use a `where in` clause

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID 
WHERE Employees.EmployeeID IN (1,2,3);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID where Employees.EmployeeID IN (1,2,3);
```

Inner join with employee id will fetch all matching records of both orders and employees with condition of employee id and then on that where clause to fetch those records whose employee id is 1,2,3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `in` operator in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID and Employees.EmployeeID in (1,2,3);
```